# Discrete Baker's Map

Tags: code-golf, string, grid

## Introduction

The [Baker's map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_map) is an important dynamical system that exhibits chaotic behavior.
It is a function from the unit square to itself defined intuitively as follows.

- Cut the square vertically in half, resulting in two rectangles of size `0.5×1`.
- Stack the right half on top of the left, resulting in one rectangle of size `0.5×2`
- Compress the rectangle back into a `1×1` square.

In this challenge, you'll implement a discrete version of this transformation.

## Input and Output

Your input is a 2D array of printable ASCII characters and whitespace of size `2m×2n` for some `m, n > 0`.
Your output is a similar array obtained as follows, using the `6×4` array

```
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX
```

as an example.
First, stack the right half of the array on top of the left half:

```
DEF
JKL
PQR
VWX
ABC
GHI
MNO
STU
```

Then, split the columns into pairs of characters, and independently turn each pair 90 degrees clockwise, "compressing" the tall rectangle back to the original shape:

```
JDKELF
VPWQXR
GAHBIC
SMTNUO
```

This is the correct output for the above array.

## Rules

The input and output formats are flexible.
You can use newline-delimited strings, lists of strings, or 2D arrays of characters.
However, the input and output **must** have the exact same format: you must be able to iterate your submission an arbitrary number of times on any valid input.

You can write either a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Test Cases

```
Input:
12
34

Output:
42
31

Input:
Hell
!  o
d  -
lroW

Output:
 lol
o W-
!H e
ldr 

Input:
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX

Output:
JDKELF
VPWQXR
GAHBIC
SMTNUO

Input:
*___  ___  o
o|__) |__) *
*|    |    o
o __   __  *
*|    | _  o
o|__  |__| *

Output:
|_____)   *o
 |_ _     *o
||_ __|   *o
o*|_____)   
o* |_ _     
o*||_ _
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>25</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
msC_dcs_Cmck/lk2Q2
```

[Online demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=msC_dcsCm_ck%2Flk2Q2&input=%5B(%27A%27%2C+%27B%27%2C+%27C%27%2C+%27D%27%2C+%27E%27%2C+%27F%27)%2C+(%27G%27%2C+%27H%27%2C+%27I%27%2C+%27J%27%2C+%27K%27%2C+%27L%27)%2C+(%27M%27%2C+%27N%27%2C+%27O%27%2C+%27P%27%2C+%27Q%27%2C+%27R%27)%2C+(%27S%27%2C+%27T%27%2C+%27U%27%2C+%27V%27%2C+%27W%27%2C+%27X%27)%5D&debug=0). It uses an 2D-array of chars.

Array of strings is one char longer (19 bytes). [Online demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mssC_dcs_Cmck%2Flk2Q2&input=%5B%27ABCDEF%27%2C%20%27GHIJKL%27%2C%20%27MNOPQR%27%2C%20%27STUVWX%27%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
         m      Q    map each string k in input:
            /lk2        calculate half the line-length: len(k)/2
          ck/lk2        chop k into pieces of length len(k)/2
                        results in two pieces
        C            zip the resulting list
                     results in a tuple ([first half of strings], [second half of strings])
       _             invert the order ([second half of strings], [first half of strings])
      s              sum (combine the two lists to a big one
     c           2   chop them into tuples
m                          for each tuple of strings: 
 sC_d                        invert, zip, and sum
```

The last part is a bit confusing at first. Let's assume we have the tuple `['DEF', 'JKL']` (I use the example from the OP).

```
    d  (('D', 'E', 'F'), ('J', 'K', 'L'))   just the pair of strings
   _d  (('J', 'K', 'L'), ('D', 'E', 'F'))   invert the order
  C_d  [('J', 'D'), ('K', 'E'), ('L', 'F')] zipped
 sC_d  ('J', 'D', 'K', 'E', 'L', 'F')       sum (combine tuples)
```

Comment: I'm not kidding you, I just independantly wrote the _exact_ same solution as you did. I did gloss over all answers to get an idea, but nothing detailed.

Comment: @orlp Yeah, it's quite often that the straightforward approach in Pyth is the shortest. So multiple people find it easily.

Comment: @orlp Btw, just made a pull request to the Pyth repo (not accepted yet). In the future you can simply do `c2k` instead of `ck/lk2`. `c2k` splits the string into two equal parts.

Answer (score 9):

## Julia, 136 bytes

A very straightforward implementation. Not a particularly competitive entry, but it was fun!

```r
A->(s=size(A);w=s[2];u=w÷2;C=vcat(A[:,u+1:w],A[:,1:u]);D=cell(s);j=1;for i=1:2:size(C,1) D[j,:]=vec(flipdim(C[i:i+1,:],1));j+=1end;D)
```

This creates a lambda function that accepts a 2-dimensional array as input and returns a transformed 2-dimensional array.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
function f(A)

    # Determine bounds
    s = size(A)          # Store the array dimensions
    w = s[2]             # Get the number of columns
    u = w ÷ 2            # Integer division, equivalent to div(w, 2)

    # Stack the right half of A atop the left
    C = vcat(A[:, u+1:w], A[:, 1:u])

    # Initialize the output array with the appropriate dimensions
    D = cell(s)

    # Initialize a row counter for D
    j = 1

    # Loop through all pairs of rows in C
    for i = 1:2:size(C, 1)

        # Flip the rows so that each column is a flipped pair
        # Collapse columns into a vector and store in D
        D[j, :] = vec(flipdim(C[i:i+1, :], 1))

        j += 1
    end

    return D
end
```

To call it, give the function a name, e.g. `f=A->(...)`.

Example output:

```r
julia> A = ["A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F";
            "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L";
            "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R";
            "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X"]
julia> f(A)

4x6 Array{Any,2}:
 "J"  "D"  "K"  "E"  "L"  "F"
 "V"  "P"  "W"  "Q"  "X"  "R"
 "G"  "A"  "H"  "B"  "I"  "C"
 "S"  "M"  "T"  "N"  "U"  "O"

julia> B = ["H" "e" "l" "l";
            "!" " " " " "o";
            "d" " " " " "-";
            "l" "r" "o" "W"]
julia> f(B)

4x4 Array{Any,2}:
 " "  "l"  "o"  "l"
 "o"  " "  "W"  "-"
 "!"  "H"  " "  "e"
 "l"  "d"  "r"  " "
```

And proof that it can be arbitrarily chained:

```r
julia> f(f(B))

4x4 Array{Any,2}:
 "W"  "o"  "-"  "l"
 "r"  " "  " "  "e"
 "o"  " "  " "  "l"
 "l"  "!"  "d"  "H"
```

Suggestions are welcome as always, and I'll happy provide any further explanation.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
qN/_0=,2/f/z~\+2/Wf%:zN*
```

Straight forward spec implementation. Explanation:

```
qN/                       "Split input by rows";
   _0=,2/                 "Get half of length of each row";
         f/               "Divide each row into two parts";
           z              "Convert array of row parts to array of half columns parts";
            ~\+           "Put the second half of columns before the first half and join";
               2/         "Group adjacent rows";
                 Wf%      "Flip the row pairs to help in CW rotation";
                    :z    "Rotate pairwise column elements CW";
                      N*  "Join by new line";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F_0%3D%2C2%2Ff%2Fz%7E%5C%2B2%2FWf%25%3AzN*&input=ABCDEF%0AGHIJKL%0AMNOPQR%0ASTUVWX)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 104  <s>141</s>

**Edit** Reviewing the spec, I found that the number of rows must be even (I missed this before). So it's not too complicated find the correct source position for each char in output in a single step.

```js
F=a=>a.map((r,i)=>
  [...r].map((c,k)=>
     a[l=i+i]?a[(j=l+1)-k%2][(k+r.length)>>1]:a[l-j-k%2][k>>1]
  ).join('')
)
```

**Test** In Firefox/FireBug console

```js
;[["ABCDEF","GHIJKL","MNOPQR","STUVWX"]
 ,["12","34"], ["Hell","!  o","d  -","lroW"]
 ,["*___  ___  o","o|__) |__) *","*|    |    o","o __   __  *","*|    | _  o","o|__  |__| *"]
].forEach(v=>console.log(v.join('\n')+'\n\n'+F(v).join('\n')))
```

*Output*

```
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX

JDKELF
VPWQXR
GAHBIC
SMTNUO

12
34

42
31

Hell
!  o
d  -
lroW

 lol
o W-
!H e
ldr 

*___  ___  o
o|__) |__) *
*|    |    o
o __   __  *
*|    | _  o
o|__  |__| *

|_____)   *o
 |_ _     *o
||_ __|   *o
o*|_____)   
o* |_ _     
o*||_ _
```

Answer (score 5):

## J, <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```
   $$[:,@;@|.@|:([:,:~2,2%~1{$)<@|:@|.;.3]
```

J has a tessellation function (cut `;.`) which helps a lot.

```
   ]input=.4 6$97}.a.
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
stuvwx

   ($$[:,@;@|.@|:([:,:~2,2%~1{$)<@|:@|.;.3]) input
jdkelf
vpwqxr
gahbic
smtnuo
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48066/134) for another way to solve the challenge in J.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>128</s> 127 bytes

```
import Control.Monad
f=g.ap((++).map snd)(map fst).map(splitAt=<<(`div`2).length)
g(a:b:c)=(h=<<zip b a):g c
g x=x
h(a,b)=[a,b]
```

Usage: `f ["12", "34"]` -> `["42","31"]`

How it works:

```
                                 input list:
                                   ["abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqr", "stuvwx"]
==========================================================================

map(splitAt=<<(`div`2).length)   split every line into pairs of halves:
                                   -> [("abc","def"),("ghi","jkl"),("mno","pqr"),("stu","vwx")]
ap((++).map snd)(map fst)        take all 2nd elements of the pairs and
                                 put it in front of the 1st elements:
                                   -> ["def","jkl","pqr","vwx","abc","ghi","mno","stu"]
(    zip b a) : g c              via g: take 2 elements from the list and
                                 zip it into pairs (reverse order), 
                                 recur until the end of the list:
                                   -> [[('j','d'),('k','e'),('l','f')],[('v','p'),('w','q'),('x','r')],[('g','a'),('h','b'),('i','c')],[('s','m'),('t','n'),('u','o')]]
h=<<                             convert all pairs into a two element list
                                 and concatenate:
                                   -> ["jdkelf","vpwqxr","gahbic","smtnuo"]
```

Edit: @Zgarb found a byte to save.

Comment: Nice! You can save 1 byte by doing `g x=x` for the empty list case.

Answer (score 3):

### J, <s>33</s> 32 characters

A monadic verb.

```
0 2,.@|:_2|.\"1-:@#@{.(}.,.{.)|:
```

#### Explanation

Let's begin by defining `Y` to be our sample input.

```
   ] Y =. a. {~ 65 + i. 4 6          NB. sample input
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX
```

The first part (`-:@#@{. (}. ,. {.) |:`) splits `Y` in half and appends then ends:

```
   # {. Y                            NB. number of columns in Y
6
   -: # {. Y                         NB. half of that
3
   |: Y                              NB. Y transposed
AGMS
BHNT
CIOU
DJPV
EKQW
FLRX
   3 {. |: Y                         NB. take three rows
AGMS
BHNT
CIOU
   3 }. |: Y                         NB. drop three rows
DJPV
EKQW
FLRX
   3 (}. ,. {.) |: Y                 NB. stitch take to drop
DJPVAGMS
EKQWBHNT
FLRXCIOU
```

In the second part (`_2 |.\"1`) we split this into pairs of two and reverse them:

```
   R =. (-:@#@{. (}. ,. {.) |:) Y    NB. previous result
   _2 <\"1 R                         NB. pairs put into boxes
┌──┬──┬──┬──┐
│DJ│PV│AG│MS│
├──┼──┼──┼──┤
│EK│QW│BH│NT│
├──┼──┼──┼──┤
│FL│RX│CI│OU│
└──┴──┴──┴──┘
   _2 <@|.\"1 R                      NB. reversed pairs
┌──┬──┬──┬──┐
│JD│VP│GA│SM│
├──┼──┼──┼──┤
│KE│WQ│HB│TN│
├──┼──┼──┼──┤
│LF│XR│IC│UO│
└──┴──┴──┴──┘
```

Finally (`0 2 ,.@|:`), we transpose the matrix as needed and discard the trailing axis:

```
   ] RR =. _2 |.\"1 R                NB. previous result
JD
VP
GA
SM

KE
WQ
HB
TN

LF
XR
IC
UO
   0 2 |: RR                         NB. transpose axes
JD
KE
LF

VP
WQ
XR

GA
HB
IC

SM
TN
UO
   ($ RR) ; ($ 0 2 |: RR)            NB. comparison of shapes
┌─────┬─────┐
│3 4 2│4 3 2│
└─────┴─────┘
   ,. 0 2 |: RR                      NB. discard trailing axis
JDKELF
VPWQXR
GAHBIC
SMTNUO
```

The whole expression with whitespace inserted:

```
0 2 ,.@|: _2 |.\"1 -:@#@{. (}. ,. {.) |:
```

And as an explicit verb:

```
3 : ',. 0 2 |: _2 |.\"1 (-: # {. y) (}. ,. {.) |: y'
```

Answer (score 3):

## GNU sed -r, 179 bytes

Score includes +1 for the `-r` arg to sed.

It took me a while to figure out how to do this in `sed`, but I think I have it now:

```
# Insert : markers at start and end of each row
s/  /:  :/g
s/(^|$)/:/g
# Loop to find middle of each row
:a
# Move row start and end markers in, one char at a time
s/:([^  :])([^  :]*)([^ :]):/\1:\2:\3/g
ta
# Loop to move left half of each row to end of pattern buffer
:b
s/([^   :]+)::(.*)/\2   \1/
tb
# remove end marker
s/$/:/
# double loop to merge odd and even rows
:c
# move 1st char of rows 2 and 1 to end of pattern buffer
s/^([^  :])([^  ]*) ([^ ])(.*)/\2   \4\3\1/
tc
# end of row; remove leading tab and add trailing tab 
s/^ +(.*)/\1    /
tc
# remove markers and trailing tab
s/(:|   $)//g
```

Note all the whitespace above should be single <kbd>tab</kbd> characters.  Comments are not included in the golf score.

Note also that this makes extensive use of `:` marker characters.  If the input stream contains `:`, then undefined behaviour will ensue.  This can be mitigated by replacing all `:` with some non-printing character (e.g. BEL) at no cost to the golf score.

Input and output is a tab-separated list of strings:

```
$ echo 'Hell
!  o
d  -
lroW' | paste -s - | sed -rf baker.sed | tr '\t' '\n'
 lol
o W-
!H e
ldr 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 18 bytes

```
mΣmm↔TmC2T§+m→m←m½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fc4tzcR21TQnKdjUIOLdcGsicB8YTcQ3v///8freTo5Ozi6qako@Tu4enl7QNk@Pr5BwQGARnBIaFh4RFKsQA)

Gaming