# Counting cycles in a folding and squashing process

Tags: code-golf, binary

In [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), the [horseshoe map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_map) is an example of how chaos arises in a simple process of folding and squashing. It goes like this: take an imaginary piece of dough, fold it, and finally squash it to its original size. Chaos arises in the pattern of how the pieces of dough end up in the final arrangement after n iterations.

[image: Example of an invariant measure]

In our case, we'll take a look at how [a simple binary pattern behaves when we fold and squash it](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/stretch/). Here are the steps with an 8-bit example (the binary representation of 201 or `11001001`).

1. Cut the bits in two pieces of equal length (add a '0' at the beginning if there is an odd number of bits).

   `1100 | 1001`
2. Fold the first half over the second half. Note that the order of the first half is reversed, as we rotate it while folding.

   `0011` 
   `1001`
3. Squash to its original shape. While squashing, the upper bits are shifted left to the bits under their original position.

   `01001011`

If we repeat this for this example, we can see that after 4 iterations, we are back to the original bitstring:

```
Start  bits: 11001001
Iteration 1: 01001011
Iteration 2: 01001101
Iteration 3: 01011001
Iteration 4: 11001001
```

So, for the decimal value of 201, the number of cycles is 4.

### The challenge

- Write a full program that takes a decimal number as input and outputs the number of cycles it takes to repeat in the above described binary squash-and-fold process.
- The (decimal) input must be taken from stdin (range: from 1 up to [Googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) or 10^100).
- The (decimal) output must be written to stdout.
- Your score is the number of bytes of your code.
- Your answer must begin with [Programming language] - [Score in bytes]
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.

### Examples

```
7 --> 3
43 --> 5
178 --> 4
255 --> 1
65534 --> 1
65537 --> 12
1915195950546866338219593388801304344938837974777392666909760090332935537657862595345445466245217915 --> 329
```

### Final note

What's interesting is that the number of cycles is related to the length of the binary representation, except for a few exceptions where the number of cycles is shorter because of the pattern in the bitstring (for example `111110` cycles after 1 iteration). This creates an interesting opportunity to optimize code length using the underlying pattern instead of calculating the number of cycles.

Comment: If the bit length of the number shortens during iteration, do we cut and fold using the original bit length, or the current one?

Comment: @xnor I would assume the original one, otherwise you would never complete cycle, right?

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48027/discrete-bakers-map/48078#48078

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 34 bytes

```
q~2b_,2%,\+{__,2//~\W%.\_W$=!}g;],
```

Nothing fancy, it just applies the map until we get back to the input, and print the number of iterations that took.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~2b_%2C2%25%2C%5C%2B%7B__%2C2%2F%2F~%5CW%25.%5C_W%24%3D!%7Dg%3B%5D%2C&input=1915195950546866338219593388801304344938837974777392666909760090332935537657862595345445466245217915)

Comment: First in! Look at you, shooting code faster than your shadow!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>175</s> <s>154</s> 149 bytes

```
i=bin(input())[2:]
i=o='0'+i if len(i)%2 else i
c=0
j=len(i)/2
while i!=o or c==0:
 a=''
 for x,y in zip(i[:j][::-1],i[j:]):a+=x+y
 i,c=a,c+1
print c
```

[Ideone link](https://ideone.com/JP4JhA)

Thanks to [agtoever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32381/agtoever) for 27 bytes!

Comment: No need for the lambda. Once the length is even, it stays even.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks!

Comment: Change ` while 1` with `while i!=o|c==0` and drop the `if i==o:break`. Saves 5. Maybe (note sure) you also don't need `a`. Just use `i`. Saves an assignment (4 bytes). Also the assignment of j can be put outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the additional saves, @agtoever. I got a TypeError when attempting to implement the `while i!=c|c==0` replacement, but still was able to save some bytes with a standard ` or `.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

I'm typing this on my phone, so please make sure to notify me of any mistakes.

```
fqu.i_hc2Gec2GTJ.BQJ1
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqu.i_hc2Gec2GTJ.BQJ1&input=1915195950546866338219593388801304344938837974777392666909760090332935537657862595345445466245217915&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 37 bytes

```apl
≢{⊃,/↓⍉⌽@1⊢2 ¯1⍴{2|≢⍵:0,⍵⋄⍵}⍵}⌂traj⊤⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@jzkXVj7qadfQftU1@1Nv5qGevg@GjrkVGCofWGz7q3VJtVANU8ah3q5WBDpB81N0CJGvBuKeppCgx61HXkkd9U0Fm/U/jMjIwBAA)

A full program which takes a single number as input.

The `traj` function does a lot of heavy lifting here(thanks to Bubbler for suggesting it and helping ot golf this).

The `(,,⍤0)/` idiom from APLcart is used to interleave lists together, but instead  this uses `,/↓⍉⌽` since it is a matrix.

### Explanation

```apl
≢{⊃,/↓⍉⌽@1⊢2 ¯1⍴{2|≢⍵:0,⍵⋄⍵}⍵}⌂traj⊤⎕
                                   ⊤⎕ convert input to base-2
 {                           }⌂traj   calculate trajectory when the following function is applied repeatedly:
                {2|≢⍵:0,⍵⋄⍵}⍵         prepend a 0 if there are an odd number of bits
           2 ¯1⍴                     cut into two rows
       ⌽@1⊢                          apply reverse to first row
   ,/↓⍉                              transpose, concatenate into a vector
  ⊃                                  unenclose
≢                                    get length of the resulting list
```